# Как защитить программу от запуска на другом компьютере?

Tags: java

Как недопустить запуск программы в другом филиале организации?
Имена компьютеров там будут отличаться по известной маске. Но получить имя компьютера очень заметный метод в коде. Его сразу заметят и поправят. Нужно проверять что то другое, не очевидное на первый взгляд. Из реестра какой-нибудь ключ возможно? Программа небольшая. Разве что специально добавить побольше классов.

Comment: Сделать это невозможно в принципе. Можно только до бесконечности усложнять возможность обхода любых ограничений. Какой бы код вы не написали - его можно найти и убрать. Даже если всю логику на сервер вынесите - можно и на сервер достучаться при желании, даже если доступ к клиенту будет осуществляться с физического токена (флешка с паролем в триллионы символов длинной) - токен просто физически украдут или скопируют его содержимое.

Comment: сделать это действительно невозможно, хотя когда-то у меня была примерно аналогичная задача. насколько я помню, использовали это https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.oshi/oshi-core для считывания инфы о железе, плюс шифрование, плюс прогард, да и кода в софте было довольно много. в общем у клиента жалоб не было, хотя , разумеется, это тоже можно взломать. это скорее ответ на вопрос, как привязать софт к конкретной машине, чем как обеспечить защиту

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Речь идет о простенькой защите.  Опыт программирования у конкурента либо нулевой, либо как у меня) Одно дело, в коде будет видно что читается имя компьютера, другое дело,если  явно не видно. А глубоко вникать в чужой код коллега не станет я думаю. Вот и хотелось совместно подумать как его можно запутать.

Comment: https://protector4j.com можете оценить с практической точки зрения? Те я зашифрую код, и смогу его запускать только с использованием этой программы. Вроде неплохо?

Comment: Он бесплатный на 7 дней походу)